# Relay Contact Rating

Tags: arduino, relay, maximum-ratings

I have an `HJR-4102E-L-05` relay that has a contact rating of 3A/120VAC. I was curious if it would be able to switch a 100 watt 120VAC lamp. I know that the relay is rated to 360 watts. My concern is that the voltage is at the 120VAC rating and the 'C' terminal on the relay will be connected to my brand new Arduino.

Comment: A link to the relay would help

Comment: I've added the link to the datasheet, @TheNextBillGates, but please remember to do this in the future.

Comment: Looks like a 90W rating to me

Comment: 'C' terminal connected to arduino - what does that mean? The data sheet doesn't mention a 'C' terminal. Do you mean the arduino drives the coil? I apologize for using recognizable nomenclature.

Comment: I did indeed mean that the Arduino drives the coil, sorry I haven't done hardly any work with electrical components and a text I read somewhere online referred to the terminal that drives the coil as the 'c' terminal.

Comment: Uh.... the coil has two terminals. What do you mean when you say *the* terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the relay can switch 0.85A/120V if it is rated at 3A/120V. (Actually, the relay is also rated at 360 VA /and 90 Watts,/ so a 100 Watt lamp may be just above the grade for this relay, depending on how that Watt rating was calculated.)

The electrical insulation of the relay is rated at > 500V, so if you keep your soldering and wiring correctly isolated, you'll be fine. Wrap all bare conductors in electrical tape to avoid accidents.

It is unlikely that the relay will be properly driven directly by the Arduino. The Arduino is specified to 25 mA output per pin (with a 40 mA max) and most relay coils that are 5V capable draw 60 mA or more, and thus would burn out the Arduino output pin. You will need a small-signal transistor or MOSFET to actually pull the coil of that relay. Try a BS170, with the Arduino driving the gate, and the relay being between drain and positive DC voltage, and the source being tied to ground.

Finally, I don't understand what you mean by "C terminal." I assume you mean the "coil" terminal. A "Form C relay" is a relay that switches one input (or more) between two separate outputs (or more.) Keeping 120V on one half and an Arduino on the other half of such a relay seems unwise.

Comment: +1 An arduino will typically not be able to properly drive a large relay just like it will not be able to source enough current for all but the smallest dc motors

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. The relay came with a beginners android kit and a has a transistor to pull the coil but thanks for letting me know why the relay is not connected to the output pin. Also I figured if the lamp has a 100 watt bulb then it would pull roughly 100 watts. If I switch the bulb to say a 60 watt bulb then the lamp would be well within the range that the relay can drive, right?

Comment: Yes, a 60 Watt lamp would draw 60 Watts. I actually think the "90 Watt" rating is for DC loads (where the relay is rated at 24 V) and the 360 VA rating is for AC loads, and the lamp is an AC load, so I think the 100 Watt lamp would work fine, assuming all other connections are right.